# Antonym of "low-ball" as price

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is an antonym or popularly used phrase meaning the opposite of *low-ball* used to refer to a price?

Comment: You ask this like its a given there is one. Not every word or phrase has an antonym.

Comment: I rephrased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lowball#Antonyms), the answer is *highball*.

Answer (score 3):

["Lowball"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lowball) means:

> To give (a customer) a deceptively low price or cost estimate that one has no intention of honoring or to prepare a cost estimate deliberately and misleadingly low.
>   To make an offer well below an item's true value, often to take advantage of the seller's desperation or desire to sell the item quickly.

Thus, the direct opposite would have to be ["Highball"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/highball) :

> To make an estimate which tends toward exaggeration.

Comment: I never heard anybody say "highball" (in reference to a price) but still it could be right.

Comment: I'm surprised, it's pretty common (relative to lowball, at least).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the word [gouge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gouge). It means to overcharge, as in "price gouging".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please remember to include a reference to your answers to make them more reliable. (:

Comment: When someone low-balls it means that they bid much less than the generally accepted fair market price. That is, the buyer is the one doing the low-balling.  The opposite, therefore, must be when the buyer overbids.

Comment: Okay. But low-balling implies deliberate underbidding. When would one ever deliberately overbid?

Comment: Perhaps when they want to discourage everyone else from even attempting to bid.  Maybe I want to buy a house.  I know others are interested as well so I make an offer at more than asking price.

Comment: I see. I guess there are two types of situations to consider. One is a public auction, where other bidders are present, in which case lowballing and highballing are strategies for a potential buyer, and gouging isn't applicable. The other is when dealing with one-on-one negotiations, like bargaining. In that case, lowballing is a buyer strategy, and gouging is a seller strategy, and highballing doesn't really apply.